# Flask: Make Application State Persist over tabs

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask and am trying to create an application that can remotely control a voltage supply to set voltage/current and turn the voltage supply on and off on and off. With these actions, I would like to update some info on the webpage.

The issue I'm running into is, if, for example, I set the power/current, I see the stats show up on the web page in the current table I'm in. But if I copy the same URL into another tab, I do not see the stats. Is there a way to show the stats on all web pages?

Below is a snippet from my server.py. I think it has something to do with the return values and what I'm rendering upon return, but I'm not sure now to fix this.

```
@application.route('/set-power-current', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def set_power_current():
    if request.method == "POST":
        req = request.form
        ip = req["ip"]
        serial = req["serial"]
        power = req["power"]
        current = req["current"]
        channel = req["channel"]

        set_power_current_channel(ip, serial, power, current, channel)

        feedback = {"Power": power, 
                    "Current":current,
                    "Channel":channel
                    }
        if int(channel) == 1:
            return render_template('index_server.html', data1=feedback)
        if int(channel) == 2:
            return render_template('index_server.html', data2=feedback)
        if int(channel) == 3:
            return render_template('index_server.html', data3=feedback)
        return redirect(request.url)

    return render_template('index_server.html')
```

Here is a snippet from my index_server.html to post the stats

```
<h2>Channel Stats</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Channel 1</h2>
    <ul>
      {% if data1 %}
              <li>Power: {{data1.Power}}</li>
              <li>Current: {{data1.Current}}</li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Channel 2</h2>
    <ul>
      {% if data2 %}
              <li>Power: {{data2.Power}}</li>
              <li>Current: {{data2.Current}}</li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Channel 3</h2>
    <ul>
      {% if data3 %}
              <li>Power: {{data3.Power}}</li>
              <li>Current: {{data3.Current}}</li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what the current tab looks like after setting the values in Channel 3, for example:
[image]

Here is what a new tab looks like after I set the values:
[image]

I would like to find a way for both tabs to look the same after values are set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the stats to show on multiple pages, you should store them and not only display them.

You can easily make use of a database like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to store the statistics and retrieve them after. It will then be consistent across all tabs/ pages.

Comment: I created  db instance called "stats' but whenever I try to add to the db inside a route function, I get an error saying that there is no such database called "stats." I think the issue is that the routes do not have knowledge of the db instance (which I declare globally). Is there a way to allow routes to know about my db instance? thanks!